# Is it possible to do string-replacements in RavenDB javascript-patches?

Tags: ravendb, ravendb-studio

Case: when spawning new dev-environments, I would like to go through some collections and change TLD's in certain string-values, so e.g. *"bla bla mydomain.com"* becomes *"bla bla mydomain.localhost"*.

I tried simply in patch-window in Raven Studio:

```js
this.MyProperty = this.MyProperty.replace(".com", ".localhost");
```

But I got:

> TypeError: Property 'replace' of object is not a function

After that I went to [the docs](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.5/csharp/client-api/commands/patches/how-to-use-javascript-to-patch-your-documents), where indeed it seems string-replacement is not an option.

My question is: is it possible in any way to do string-replacement in js-patches in RavenDB?

Answer (score 1):

This should just work:

```
this.Name = this.Name.replace("food", "drink");
```

I just tested it on http://live-test.ravendb.net/studio/index.html#databases/patch/recentpatch--374082468?&database=Northwind and it does work.

However, make sure that the property actually exists and is of type string.

Answer (score 0):

Ah - found out 5 minutes later:

```js
_.replace(this.MyProperty, ".com", ".localhost");
```

As [docs say](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.5/java/client-api/commands/patches/how-to-use-javascript-to-patch-your-documents), underscore`_` references the [lodash library](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.13.1/doc/README.md) (hashtag rtfm)

Comment: lodash works. However, .replace works too. I'm guessing you just needed to a do a null or undefined check, e.g. if (this.Name) { this.Name.replace(...) }